# ColdFusion Site Keeps Crashing Every Day

Tags: coldfusion, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-6, windows-server-2008, coldfusion-9

I have a Windows Server 2008 with IIS 6. There are 5 ColdFusion 9 sites running on the server. There are 2 specific sites that keep crashing every day and I am not able to track down the cause of the crash. The site simply stops responding to any requests. At the time of crash the SQL server looks good (no deadlocks found).

In order to bring the site back online I just need to restart the ColdFusion server or IIS services. ColdFusion logs look good and there is no error found in the IIS logs of the site. There is enough space on the 'C' drive so that the logs can grow.

What else am I missing? Please help me to find the cause of crash.

Comment: Did you check ColdFusion logs? If the logs are clean, then probably the App pools might be crashing. Enable Failed Request tracing in IIS https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5f5bd256-7d1f-4239-9a7f-8eea4072fcb3.mspx?mfr=true and check the logs, after the crash.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing in the logs?  There must be something in there if ColdFusion is having problems.  Check the `cfusion-out.log` under your `JRun4\logs` folder.  That will show any ColdFusion issues.  You can also check the Windows Event log for any Windows issues.  Check the application and system event logs around the time of the crash.

Comment: When you look in the IIS logs, you are not looking for errors.  You are looking for page requests that were running at the time to help give you an indication of what caused the crash.  If you can, launch a monitor window and then look at it when things freeze up.

Comment: @Miguel: I have found this error "Request timed out waiting for an available thread to run" in the 'coldfusion-out.log'. So I have increased the thread limit and also the number of request.

What next should I look for?

Comment: @Anita: I have also Enabled the Failed Request tracing.

Comment: You need to find out which request is taking so long. It won't matter how many threads you give it, each one of those long requests will lock one up. Do you have a timeout set in the ColdFusion administrator?  Set one in the Admin under Server Settings > Settings > Timeout Requests after xx seconds. You can find the long running pages by turning on the option in the administrator. Under Debugging & Logging > Logging Settings > Log slow pages taking longer than xx seconds. Turn that on then any request taking longer than xx seconds will be logged to the ColdFusion server.log file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache server there might be location that was missing or wrongly declared. try to see the config or log files. if you are using IIS then there might be a connector problem. Try to create a new application pool